# How can I push_back data in a vector via a vector::pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I 'd like to use a vector::pointer so as to push_back data in it..

```
int num;
vector<int> v;
vector<int>::pointer ptr;

ptr = &v[0];

ptr->push_back(num);  // fail
ptr.push_back(num);  // fail
ptr.push_back(&num);  // fail
*ptr.push_back(num);  // fail
```

nothing appears to work.. any ideas would be appreciated..

Comment: If you are new to the C++ language don't be embarrassed about asking questions like this here.  If I had had such a resource on tap when I was learning C++, it would have saved me a lot of time and bafflement.  A good introductory book would be advisable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You need to use the original vector object.

If you'd like to have a pointer to a vector, you can do the following:

```
vector<int> v;
vector<int> *pointer = &v;

v.push_back(4);
pointer->push_back(3);
```

As a comment, the type of `vector<int>::pointer` in your code should be `int *`.

Comment: thank u all for your answers.. now i get it.. Problem fixed! I am not new to C++, vectors are new to me and I am a little rusty! (blush)

Comment: @Mary P: Glad to help. On Stack Overflow, it's requested that you mark an answer as the correct answer once you've found one that works for you. Beneath the voting section for each answer, there should be an outline of a checkmark that you can use to accept an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are misunderstanding what [vector::pointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e4tx21z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is.  That's a type for a pointer to an element in the vector, not a pointer to a vector itself.

That aside, it's not clear to me why you would want to do this since `.` notation works just fine and saves you the pointer dereference on each access.  If you find yourself typing in `vector<int> *vecPtr = new vector<int>;`, take a deep breath and ask why you cannot use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Answer (score 1):

in this case `ptr` is an `int*` not a pointer to a `vector<int>` so it cannot perform vector operations. When you make the assignment:

```
ptr = &v[0];
```

you're assigning the pointer to the address containing the integer at v[0], not assigning a reference to the vector. To do what you want, you need to do the following:

```
int num;
vector<int> v;
vector<int>* ptr;

ptr = &v;

ptr->push_back(num);
```