# vector::push_back and accessing values in Vector Pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Edit: The below question was answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166999/how-can-i-push-back-data-in-a-vector-via-a-vectorpointer). I have a new updated question, is it any more efficient to use: (my friend said it is inefficient to put a vector of a vector because it uses sequential memory and to realloc when you push_back means it takes more time to find the location where a chunk of memory for the entire large vector can be placed)

(where Picture is a vector of lines, Line is a vector of points)

```
std::vector<Point> *LineVec;
std::vector<Line> PictureVec;

versus

std::vector<Point> LineVec;
std::vector<Line> PictureVec;


struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

I'm trying to get a vector of a vector and my friend told me that it's inefficient to put a vector of a vector because it uses sequential memory and vector of a vector will require huge amounts of space. So what he suggested was a using a vector of a pointer vector. Therefore the inner vector looks like this. Clearly I'm very new to C++ and would appreciate any insight.

```
struct Shape{
    int c;
    int d;
}
std::vector<Shape> *intvec;
```

When I want to push back into this, how would I do so? Something like this?

```
Shape s;
s.c=1;
s.d=1;
intvec->push_back(s);
```

Also, I wrote an iterator to go through, however it does not seem to work, hence why I believe the above code does not work. Finally my last concern is, while the above code works, it gives really weird values for my output. Large numbers that are 7 digits long and definitely not the values I put in for s.c and s.d

```
for(std::vector<Shape>::iterator it=Shapes->begin();it<Shapes->end();it++){
    Shape s = (*it);
    std::cout << s.c << s.d << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your friend is wrong. A `vector` object is itself a pointer 
(with some additional members) to a contiguous array, so you're introducing an extra level of indirection and wasting some more space.

Comment: What exactly don't work? Compiler error? Runtime error? Do you intitalize your intvec pointer anywhere (with new std::vector<Shape>())?

Comment: @larsmans A vector object is not itself a pointer but it contains a pointer to buffer internally , I know you know that but still wanted to spill it out xD

Comment: Thanks @larsmans, just wondering, can you answer the question so I can mark you're answer as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a vector of pointers to vectors is *not* more efficient than a vector of vectors. It's less efficient, because it introduces an extra level of indirection. It also does *not* cause all elements of the resulting 2-d array to be allocated contiguously.

The reason is that a vector is practically a pointer to an array, in the sense that a `vector<T>` is implemented roughly as

```
 template <typename T>
 class vector
 {
     T *p;  // pointer to array of elements
     size_t nelems, capacity;

   public:
     // interface
 };
```

so that a vector of vectors behaves, performance-wise, like a dynamic array of pointers to arrays.

[Note: I can't quote the C++ standard chapter and verse, but I'm pretty sure it constrains `std::vector`'s operations and complexity in such a way that the above is the only practical way of implementing it.]

Answer (score 0):

As to your updated question about whether or not it is more efficient to use a pointer to a vector over a vector itself. In some cases it is more efficient to use a pointer to a vector rather then the actual vector itself. A specific example would be using a vector as a parameter for a function.

EX:

```
void somefunction(std::vector<int> hello)
```

In this case the copy constructor for std::vector is invoked any time this function is called (which copies the vector completely, INCLUDING the elements contained in the vector). Passing by reference gets rid of this extra copy.

As for whether push_back itself is more efficient when using a pointer to a vector. No its not more efficient to use a pointer (they should be roughly equivalent time wise).